# graphql error Argument Validation Error (register form validation)

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo-client, formik

I'm using formik form library with the next js app, the problem is when I send the form data inside the variables object.
I get this error **graphql error Argument Validation Error**,
and I don't know what the problem with those values that i send

```
export const SIGN_UP = gql`
  mutation register(
    $email: String!
    $username: String!
    $display_name: String!
    $password: String!
    $type: String!
    $phone: String!
    $language: String
  ) {
    register(
      input: {
        email: $email
        username: $username
        display_name: $display_name
        password: $password
        phone: $phone
        type: $type
        language: $language
      }
    ) {
      token
      user {
        username
        email_verified
        is_verified
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

this is the register component where I call the mutation SIGN_UP
but when I press the submit button I get the error of "graphql error Argument Validation Error"

````
 const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      username: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      confirmPassword: "",
      phone: "3211231290421",
      type: "member",
      language: "en",
    },
    onSubmit: async (values) => {
      let input = {
        username: values.username,
        display_name: values.username,
        email: values.email,
        password: values.password,
        phone: values.phone,
        type: values.type,
        language: values.language,
      };

      try {
        const response = await addUser({
          variables: input,
        });
        console.log(response);
      } catch (err: any) {
        return;
      }
    },
    validationSchema: regsiterSchema,
  });```
````

Comment: what is the `regsiterSchema`?

Comment: @nima that's just Yup schema for the input requirement and validations for example "FullName must contain at least 6 characters " , I hope you understand now.

Comment: mutation tested in the playground (using the same variables)?

Comment: @xadm yes thats correct

Comment: then compare network requests